# Nox emulator startup stucks at 99%

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator

I am using Windows 10, latest version with Anniversary update.

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Pro with Xamarin and all mobile development features.

I have installed Nox latest version (3.8.0.0).

I have run into an issue with crashing Windows everytime starting Nox. Turned off Hyper V feature in Windows fixed this issue.

Then, Nox starts normally but the startup progress always stuck at 99%. I have tried everything they mentioned in the support topics, even use Windows Repair twice.

Here is the log from Nox.log file:

```
2017-02-02 00:12:36 [root]-[INFO] Start Nox Application V3.8.0.0 cmd: F:\Emulators\Nox\bin\Nox.exe 

2017-02-02 00:12:36 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] is_show_last_screen: computer resolution is changed

2017-02-02 00:12:36 [LoadingPage]-[INFO] do not to load html!

2017-02-02 00:12:37 [Utils]-[INFO] Kill 1NoxVMSVC.exe

2017-02-02 00:12:37 [Utils]-[INFO] Kill 0BigNoxProxy.exe

2017-02-02 00:12:37 [Utils]-[INFO] Kill 0NoxVMHandle.exe

2017-02-02 00:12:37 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] vm:F:/Emulators/Nox/bin/../noxvm/NOXVM.exe

2017-02-02 00:12:37 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] nox is not config

2017-02-02 00:12:37 [VMClient]-[INFO] check_vm finded vm!

2017-02-02 00:12:37 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] pt:C:\Program Files (x86)\Bignox\BigNoxVM\RT/NOXa.dll

2017-02-02 00:12:37 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] vm start begin

2017-02-02 00:12:38 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] port_valid_check return true

2017-02-02 00:12:38 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] vbox_host_udp_port_valid_check return true

2017-02-02 00:12:38 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] Vm Starts OK

2017-02-02 00:12:38 [ScreenBoard]-[INFO] input_management run


2017-02-02 00:12:38 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] Vm Starts finish

2017-02-02 00:12:38 [ScreenBoard]-[INFO] Input management connected!

2017-02-02 00:16:35 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[ERROR] vm:nox status: 5

2017-02-02 00:16:35 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] port_valid_check return true

2017-02-02 00:19:00 [NoxClient]-[ERROR] NoxClient::executeShellCommand: recv reply error: command: getprop nox.open_startscreen len < 0

2017-02-02 00:20:15 [NoxClient]-[ERROR] NoxClient::executeShellCommand: recv reply error: command: getprop sys.boot_completed len < 0

2017-02-02 00:21:31 [NoxClient]-[ERROR] NoxClient::executeShellCommand: recv reply error: command: getprop nox.open_startscreen len < 0

2017-02-02 00:21:50 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] oncloseclick msgbox check

2017-02-02 00:21:51 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] enter close_window

2017-02-02 00:21:51 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] share is not null 4096 4

2017-02-02 00:21:51 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] clean up env start

2017-02-02 00:21:51 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] last running task, clean up env

2017-02-02 00:21:53 [NoxClient]-[ERROR] NoxClient::executeShellCommand: recv reply error: command: getprop sys.boot_completed len < 0

2017-02-02 00:21:53 [Utils]-[INFO] Kill 0nox_adb.exe

2017-02-02 00:21:53 [Utils]-[INFO] Kill 1NoxVMSVC.exe

2017-02-02 00:21:53 [Utils]-[INFO] Kill 1BigNoxProxy.exe

2017-02-02 00:21:53 [Utils]-[INFO] Kill 0NoxVMHandle.exe

2017-02-02 00:21:53 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] clean up finish

2017-02-02 00:21:53 [CopyPasteListener]-[ERROR] send PING to copypastetunnel failed

2017-02-02 00:22:23 [root]-[INFO] Start Nox Application V3.8.0.0 cmd: F:\Emulators\Nox\bin\Nox.exe 

2017-02-02 00:22:23 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] is_show_last_screen: computer resolution is changed

2017-02-02 00:22:23 [LoadingPage]-[INFO] do not to load html!

2017-02-02 00:22:23 [Utils]-[INFO] Kill 1NoxVMSVC.exe

2017-02-02 00:22:23 [Utils]-[INFO] Kill 0BigNoxProxy.exe

2017-02-02 00:22:23 [Utils]-[INFO] Kill 0NoxVMHandle.exe

2017-02-02 00:22:23 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] vm:F:/Emulators/Nox/bin/../noxvm/NOXVM.exe

2017-02-02 00:22:23 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] nox is not config

2017-02-02 00:22:23 [VMClient]-[INFO] check_vm finded vm!

2017-02-02 00:22:25 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] pt:C:\Program Files (x86)\Bignox\BigNoxVM\RT/NOXa.dll

2017-02-02 00:22:25 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] vm start begin

2017-02-02 00:22:26 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] port_valid_check return true

2017-02-02 00:22:26 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] vbox_host_udp_port_valid_check return true

2017-02-02 00:22:26 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] Vm Starts OK

2017-02-02 00:22:26 [ScreenBoard]-[INFO] input_management run

2017-02-02 00:22:26 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] Vm Starts finish

2017-02-02 00:22:26 [ScreenBoard]-[INFO] Input management connected!
```

Please let me know if you have any idea to fix this one. I'd love to use Nox as it enables macro for easy testing/debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manage to fix it myself.

The key is, the installation of Nox must happen AFTER disabling Hyper-V feature in Windows 10.

So if you are having Nox/BlueStacks installed already and it stops working or doesn't work, uninstall it first, disable Hyper-V and reinstall it again.